# Why does $\frac{1}{2}\oint d(\vec U_a\cdot \vec U_a)=0$ in the derivation of Kelvin's circulation theorem (from Holten)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

From Dynamic Meteorology, Holten and Hakim, 5th edition, 2012 (pg. 97):

$\frac{1}{2}\oint d(\vec U_a\cdot \vec U_a)=0$ in the derivation of Kelvin's circulation theorem.

Where $\vec U_a$ is the velocity field in the absolute coordinate system.

The line before that, they write $\oint\nabla\phi\cdot d\vec l=\oint d\phi=0$, because the integral around a closed loop of a perfect differential is equal to zero, which I understand.

But does the same idea apply for $\oint d(\vec U_a\cdot \vec U_a)$? Why would $ d(\vec U_a\cdot \vec U_a)$ be a perfect differential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as $(\text{blah})$ is a valid function, then $d(\text{blah})$ is automatically a "perfect differential", because the *definition* of being a perfect differential is that it's $d$ of some valid function.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't it?

$\mathbf{U}_a \cdot \mathbf{U}_a = U_a^2$ which is a scalar field giving the kinetic energy/ram pressure of your fluid. Its differential element $\mathrm{d}U_a^2$ is the ram pressure for an infinitesimal volume.