# Circulation theorem

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, aerodynamics, vortex

The usual derivation of Kelvin circulation theorem start with the following steps:
$$\frac{D\Gamma}{Dt} = \frac{D}{Dt}\left (\oint_{C} \vec {V} \cdot d \vec{s}\right )= \oint_{C}\frac{D\vec{V}}{Dt}\cdot d\vec s + \oint_{C}\vec V\cdot\frac{D(d\vec{s})}{Dt}.$$
Focusing on the last integral, we have,
$$ \oint_{C}\vec V\cdot\frac{D(d\vec{s})}{Dt}=  \oint_{C}\vec V \,d\vec{V}=\oint_{C}d\left(\frac{V^2}{2}\right).$$
At this point most of textbooks say that $d\left(\frac{V^2}{2}\right)$ is an exact differential.

My question is, why do we have to move on to analyze the integral of the differential of $V^2$ (which vanishes only assuming that the [function is a single-valued function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/537581/why-does-frac12-oint-d-vec-u-a-cdot-vec-u-a-0-in-the-derivation-of-kel?rq=1)), when we can directly solve the integral knowing that in the closed circuit $a=b$, so that
$$\oint_{C}\vec V\cdot d\vec{V}=\left [\frac{1}{2}V^2  \right ]_{a}^{b}=0.$$

Comment: And please explain how you got your penultimate equal sign…

Comment: Circulation can't be always written as ordinary integral from $a$ to $a$, such integral is always zero, but circulation in general is not. It works here only because $\vec{V}\cdot d\vec{V}$ is exact differential (differential of a function of position).